# Matlab: 3D matrix of discrete values drawn from a vector

Tags: matlab, random, multidimensional-array

I would like to generate 3-dimenstional matrix M of values sampled uniformly from the array of discrete values `[0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0]`, with replacement. M should be of the dimension `n*m*m`, where n=4 and m=3.

The Matlab documentation gives an example of drawing a sequence of values from a given array using `randsample` function (http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/stats/randsample.html), but it does not seem to be able to generate multi-dimensional data…

```
population = [0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0]
z = randsample(population,m,true)
```

On the other hand, `rand` function can easily generate 3D matrices, but automatically does so only for continuous distributions bound in the required (0.2; 1.0) interval (endpoints included):

```
lowb=0.1999;                      
uppb=1.0001;
M=(uppb-lowb).*rand(n,m,m)+ lowb;
```

Is there any way to reconcile the two approaches and generate 3D matrix with discrete values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you can use `randi` and index accordingly:

```
randi(numel(population),n,m,m)./numel(population)
```

where `numel(population)=5` in your case...